# NSInvalidArgumentException reason keyboardWasHidden?

Tags: cocoa-touch, exception

What's wrong here?

```
- (IBAction)textFieldDidEndEditing:(id)sender
{
    if(!_isEditing )
        return;
    UITextField* textField = (UITextField*)sender;
    NSString* newValue = [textField text];
    UITableViewCell* cell = [self GetCellFromTextField:textField];
    NSString* fieldName =[(UILabel*)[self GetLabelHeaderFromCell:cell] text];   
    NSIndexPath* indexPath= [self GetIndexPathForCell:cell];
    [PersonalSection SetFieldValue:newValue AndFieldName:fieldName UsingIndexPath:indexPath AndPersonalInformation:self.personalInfoInUse];

    _trackingEditTextField=nil;
    [fieldName release];
    _isEditing = FALSE;

}

- (IBAction)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(id)sender
{
    _trackingEditTextField=(UITextField*)sender;
}

-(IBAction)textFieldDidChange
{
    _isEditing=YES;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveButton;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [_trackingEditTextField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}

-(void)KeyboardDidShow:(NSNotification*) notification
{
    if ( keyboardShown )
        return;

    CGRect frame = tableView.frame;
    frame.size.height -= 165;
    tableView.frame = frame;
    [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[self GetIndexPathForTextView:_trackingEditTextField] atScrollPosition:0 animated:YES];
    keyboardShown = YES;
}

- (void)keyboardWasHidden:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if ( keyboardShown ) {

        CGRect frame = tableView.frame;
        frame.size.height += 165;
        tableView.frame = frame;
        keyboardShown = NO;

    }
}
```

The exception fires when trying to resign first responder (i.e. when i click the 'done' button on the keyboard) but the keyboard is still showing and it did not enter keyboardWasHidden yet, which is the receiver of UIKeyboardWillHideNotification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was listening to the notification through the following line of code

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWasHidden::) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

so it was a small mistake,
The selector "keyboardWasHidden::" should have been "keyboardWasHidden:"

hope it's useful for anybody.